# MySql Delimiter Issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm learning stored procedures and it's going good.
I'm facing just a little issue, my 'DELIMETER ;' is left over.
Every time when i add the stored procedure it end at 'END $$' and the DELIMETER ; is not being executed.

The result looks like this:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `add_workout` (IN _duration TINYINT(255),IN _premium CHAR(255))
    -> BEGIN
    -> INSERT INTO workouts(duration,premium)  VALUES(_duration,_premium);
    -> END $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

It creates the stored procedure ,but I'm interested why does it leaves the DELIMTER at the end like this?

It executes just this part:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `add_workout` (IN _duration TINYINT(255),IN _premium CHAR(255))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO workouts(duration,premium)  VALUES(_duration,_premium);
END$$
```

And after it for example i want to call SHOW TABLES; i have to add $$ to it so that it can execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter is changed to $$. After END your statement ends with your new delimiter, so it is executed.

Press enter for the last statement to run and change it back to ;

There isn't a special reason for it to not work: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Thanks it confused me a bit :D but now it's ok